# Extremely high motherboard temperature

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, temperature

Please see attached pictures of my current PC's temperature; especially the motherboard Temp #2 reading on the top line.

A red blinking right appeared on its right side today for the first time, never had that before.

Is the Corsair one i160 normal?

Temperature from Corsair Link:

[image: Corsair link results]

Temperature from Speedfan:

[image: SpeedFan results]

Comment: Without knowing what these sensors are supposed to be, it is very hard to tell what’s going on. However, temperatures that high usually occur in the CPU’s power supply circuitry. Do you have enough air circulation in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Corsair Link appears to assume that that sensor is reporting a temperature in **Celsius**, while it might actually be reporting in **Fahrenheit** for some odd reason. 96F equals to 35C, a much more realistic number that also corresponds with what SpeedLink is reporting. Comparing it to the other temperatures, it is much more likely a misreading/defect than the actual temperature.

To confirm that the sensors are defect you could use a regular analog thermometer (the dollar store kind) and stick it in your case for a while and see what it reports. Chances are it'll be in the 30 to 40 Celsius range (assuming you didn't just play a resource demanding game for a while)

I wouldn't worry too much about it. You might also want to try MSI's own monitoring tool available on the motherboard's support page and see what that reports.

Comment: It is _very_ unlikely this is actually Fahrenheit. That would mean the other temperatures are unrealistically low.

Comment: @DanielB That's why I only think that those odd high valued sensors are reporting F. The values of Temp 1, 2 and 3 make perfect sense once converted. Since they also appear to be on the same component I just figured it's isolated to those sensors only. Why it's happening I can only guess, but temp sensors have these kind of issues all the time - One of my desktops has a GPU reporting 100C while idling no matter what I do. Hence the suggestion to check it out with an analog thermometer.

Answer (score -1):

That's too high of a temperature. If it hasn't shut off by itself due to temperature controller in the bios controls the shut down temperature.

Use common sense here. Do you believe 120C is too high? What is it normally?

Check and make sure your fans are moving , clean your case for the love of God, and don't mess with any bios settings unless u plan on living with the consequences .

If it remains in an overheating state, don't touch it until u unplug everything, wait for it to cool, so u don't burn yourself

These hardware components typically are designed to run at very high temperatures (higher than you'd ever really want idealy) and withstand such by limiting or throttling their resources as temp increases.